# How to call a function exist in libobjc.A.dylib?

Tags: objective-c, dynamic-linking, dyld, kvc

I'm studying how KVC works and I set a symbolic breakpoint `_class_getVariable` which function would be called when sending `setValue:forKey:` message to object.

So I wrote this:

`extern Ivar _class_getVariable(Class cls, const char *name, Class *memberOf);`

and add a flag `-Wl,-undefined,dynamic_lookup` into `Other Linker Flags` in building setting to specify this undefined symbol would be look up dynamically. But I still get error from dyld when I call this function:

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: __class_getVariable
Referenced from: /Users/Stan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Obj-C-aiaspdiyxsvqblfjkvreemnpekov/Build/Products/Debug/Obj-C
Expected in: flat namespace

dyld: Symbol not found: __class_getVariable
Referenced from: /Users/Stan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Obj-C-aiaspdiyxsvqblfjkvreemnpekov/Build/Products/Debug/Obj-C
Expected in: flat namespace

Program ended with exit code: 9
```

I had checked objc-rumtime's sources code, the function do exist in there. Is there any way to call it?

**Update**

I have found a function `class_getInstanceVariable` in runtime.h as a replacement to fetch ivar with name. But I'm still curious about how to call `_class_getVariable`.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Go grab the ObjC source;  I'd bet that function is leftover from some arch specific implementation and doesn't exist on the arch you are compiling for.